# Numpad keys don't throw KeyEvents under JavaFX on RaspberryPi 3

Tags: javafx, input, raspberry-pi, gluon, javafxports

While programming a JavaFX application for the Raspberry Pi 3 using the official [JavaFXPorts from Gluon](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/), I encountered the following problem: Pressing the numpad keys on my keyboard doesn't give me any `KeyEvent`, while on my normal PC it does as it should!

Here's a minimal verifiable example that demonstrates my problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class InputTest extends Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }


   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) {
      Scene s = new Scene(new Group(), 800, 600, Color.ALICEBLUE);
      s.setOnKeyPressed((e) -> {
         KeyCode code = e.getCode();
         System.out.println(code);
         if (code.equals(KeyCode.ESCAPE)) {
            System.exit(0); // To be able to exit easily.
         }
      });
      stage.setScene(s);
      stage.show();
   }
}
```

Just try pressing the numpad keys, and no events will be fired, while normal keys do work.

I have also tested it under the standard out-of-the-box Raspian and Ubuntu 16.04 for the Pi. I doesn't work on both systems, independent of the keyboard layout. In other programs the numpad works as it should.

I think that this problem applies to all embedded systems that have to use GluonJavaFXPorts (Oracle doesn't support JavaFX on embedded anymore), so it's not really a Pi-specific problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I have just migrated this question on request of a moderator at raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Cheers

Comment: I ran into this problem myself many years after the previous post was published and the problem still exists. I understand the guys at Gluon are now in charge of javafxports. Is there a way to report this as a bug or at least adequately tag it? It seems that no one is even aware of this issue.